# Regex Match without new line ^M

Tags: regex, perl, newline, vi

I have a regex in my perl script which is `/Operating System:\s*(.*)/`.
The line I am matching is `Operating System: Windows XP Service Pack 3` however, there is a new line after entered after that line. So the text would be seen as `Operating System: Windows XP Service Pack 3^M`.

Is there anyway to get rid of the `^M` using the current regex I have? It captures `Windows XP Service Pack 3^M`but the `^M` doesn't display only when I display the content using command prompt or PuTTy's `more`. It displays when I edit using `vi` or rather `vim`.

Any help on this?

Comment: Ohh sorry, I posted the wrong regex. I followed your deleted comment, it works with the `(?=\r)`. You can post it up with this regex `/Operating System:\s*(.*)/`. I'll mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: I can't see why your regex should match the trailing newline - are you certain putty doesn't do some sort of "writeln" and adds a newline after the match? (check: https://regex101.com/r/mH4fP7/1)

Comment: @pastacool Nope, that's because I'm reading from a log file, it uses `^M` for a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Operating System:\s*(.*)(?=\r)
```

You can try this.

> When Searching
>
> ...
>
> \n is newline, \r is CR (carriage return = Ctrl-M = ^M)

Comment: @hzq `.` wont match `\n` without `s` or `DOTALL` flag.So it must be matching `\r`.

Comment: This is a hack. Perl is designed to have just a LF at the end of each input line, and the CR is present only when reading wrongly-decoded cross-platform data. Coding for the presence of an artifact is bad form, and there may not be a CR at the end of the last line of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than the look-ahead for CR, I think it's more intuitive to use the pattern that I put in my solution to your main question

```
/Operating System:\s*(.*\S)/
```

which captures everything from the first to the last non-space character after `Operating System`. Apart from being more readable, this pattern's primary advantage is that is portable and doesn't rely on the presence of a trailing CR at the end of the line (which may not be present on the last line of the file anyway).

Both CR and LF count as whitespace, so it will ignore them as well as any trailing spaces or tabs that may be in the file

Comment: I like this over `/Operating System:\s*([^\r\n]+)/` cause it also ignores any trailing spaces. It would be nice if the answer stood on its own rather than building on vks's, though.

Comment: @ikegami: Why do you think it doesn't stand alone? I would agree that commenting on another solution is superfluous and probably a little catty, but I don't see that my own post relies on information from another's

Comment: @ikegami: I used to write this mechanically as `\S+(?:\s+\S+)*` until I saw the light

Comment: It's simply missing the explanation that ^M represents CR. `\S+(?:\s+\S+)*` handles match failures far better than `\s*(.*\S)`, but in this situation, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I see, I tried to do this but probably had a syntax error. +1